# Magento 2.3.4 PWA "Sorry! There are no products in this category"

Tags: magento2.3.4, pwa

I've added a product in What's New Category I can see the product in there when I navigate to non-pwa magento frontend version. But still say: "Sorry! There are no products in this category" and show no products in PWA frontend version, Run all possible `bin/magento` commands yet no sign of the product anyone has any idea why and what i need to do?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer, And have no idea that when you run `watch:all` it doesn't work as expected not even adding to cart. when I run `stage:venia` I can see the product and adding it cart also working!